# NetSuite, what happens to customer deposit linked to a sales order when a cash sale is created?

Tags: netsuite

we have got a customer deposit linked to a sales order that has been created via the e-commerce website. Now that when we try to use the create invoice feature, the system creates a cash sale by default with a warning message,

> Changing the form to a cash sale form will remove the link between the
> deposit and the sales order. The deposit will then be able to be
> applied to any open invoice. Do you want to continue?

When a cash sale is created, all the payment information captured at the sales order level is being copied onto the cash sale record as-is and the order is marked as billed.

Now, what happens to the customer deposit that has been unlinked. Also, on the make deposits page, we see both customer deposit & cash sales and it looks like a double-up of payments.

Please suggest how to resolve this situation if anyone had encountered this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netsuite automatically converts "Sales Order - Cash Sale" to "Sales Order - Invoice" when a deposit is linked to the SO. So something in your account is attempting to change it back when billing. Maybe a person, script or workflow is overriding the custom form when billing but what you are describing is not vanila Netsuite behaviour.

The only way I can see that happening the way you describe is if someone had inactivated all the Sales Order - Invoice transaction forms. (that's a guess since I haven't seen an account set up like that but it's quick to check).

And yes if you have a cash sale and a deposit that is a double bill and may result in a chargeback or at least make a mess of your accounts.

Comment: Thank you, Brett. If I change the form to invoice version, we would be losing the payment information say the payment method for Paypal or bank transfers. What you said works for card transactions perfectly.

Comment: If your other sales don’t have a deposit leave them as Cash Sales